# How many array accesses for the following

Tags: java, arrays, runtime, time-complexity

I have the following question.
Give the Tilde Approximation for the number of Array accesses for the following code

```
for (int i=0; i < n; ++i)
    for (int j = i/2; j < i; ++j)
        A[i] = B[j] + C[j];
```

However, I cannot figure out exactly how many array accesses there are, in terms of N

And i thought the answer would `n^3` -- n for A, and n^2 for both B and C.

Do i seem to be on the right tack?

Answer (score 0):

The N order is N^2 for big O notation.

This is due to 2 nested for loops.

Comment: So there's n^2 array accesses your saying?

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that there is no compiler/jir optimizations, we have:

1) all arrays have the same amount of accesses

2) second for is performed ~ i/2 times

3) total sum(i=0,i=n) i/2 = O(n^2) (The sum of the first n natural numbers)

Comment: Yes, total amount  is O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't count like that

your array A[] is been access the same times as B[] and C[], the only difference is that A is access `j` times at `i` position.

and other thing, is not nˆ3, you can't do A times B, you should analyze the both for`s to count the complexity

so, first for execute `n`times, second for execute `n/2` times

In this case you have `O(nˆ2 / 4)` or just `O(nˆ2)`

Comment: OH okay that makes sense actually, The only thing i don't get it is why you went to `O(n^2 / 4)` shouldn't it be `O(n^2 / 2)`?

Comment: That's happens because you are working with natural numbers, so for example, for n = 1 and n = 2. you have 1 interaction at second loop..so half of your interactions are the same..in this case (N*N/2)/2